# add labels to left and right of nodes

Tags: graphviz

I have this input:

```
graph {
"1" -- "11"
"11" -- "111"
"1" -- "12"
"12" -- "121"
"12" -- "122"
}
```

Which will produce this graph

[image]

Is it possible to add labels to the left and right side of nodes so the output will be something like this?

[image]

No need to use strictly graphviz/DOT

Answer (score 1):

It is possible with a little graphviz "hack" using labels of edges from and to the same node, but hiding the edge (penwidth=0):

```
graph {
    edge [penwidth=0];
    "1":w -- "1":w  [taillabel="1"]
    "1":e -- "1":e  [taillabel="12"]
    "11":n -- "11":w  [taillabel="21"] // north - west
    "11":e -- "11":e  [taillabel="21"]
    "12":w -- "12":w  [taillabel="1"]
    "12":e -- "12":e  [taillabel="6"]
    "111":w -- "111":w  [taillabel="1"]
    "111":e -- "111":e  [taillabel="6"]
    "121":w -- "121":w  [taillabel="1"]
    "121":e -- "121":e  [taillabel="6"]
    "122":w -- "122":w  [taillabel="1"]
    "122":e -- "122":e  [taillabel="6"]
    edge [penwidth=1];
    
    "1" -- "11"
    "11" -- "111"
    "1" -- "12"
    "12" -- "121"
    "12" -- "122"
}
```

[image: graphviz graph output]

Answer (score 0):

If you are flexible as to node shape, here is a solution using html-like nodes https://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/shapes.html#html.  A little verbose, but easy to produce programmatically.

```
graph {
    graph [splines=false]
    node  [shape=plaintext]
    N1 [label=<
      <TABLE BORDER="0" CELLBORDER="1" CELLSPACING="0">
        <TR>
      <TD BORDER="0">1</TD><TD PORT="p1">1</TD><TD BORDER="0">12</TD>
    </TR>
      </TABLE>>];
    N2 [label=<
      <TABLE BORDER="0" CELLBORDER="1" CELLSPACING="0">
        <TR>
      <TD BORDER="0">21</TD><TD PORT="p2">11</TD><TD BORDER="0">21</TD>
    </TR>
      </TABLE>>];
    N3 [label=<
      <TABLE BORDER="0" CELLBORDER="1" CELLSPACING="0">
        <TR>
      <TD BORDER="0">1</TD><TD PORT="p3">12</TD><TD BORDER="0">6</TD>
    </TR>
      </TABLE>>];
   N4 [label=<
      <TABLE BORDER="0" CELLBORDER="1" CELLSPACING="0">
        <TR>
      <TD BORDER="0">1</TD><TD PORT="p4">11</TD><TD BORDER="0">6</TD>
    </TR>
      </TABLE>>];
   N5 [label=<
      <TABLE BORDER="0" CELLBORDER="1" CELLSPACING="0">
        <TR>
      <TD BORDER="0">1</TD><TD PORT="p5">121</TD><TD BORDER="0">6</TD>
    </TR>
      </TABLE>>];
   N6 [label=<
      <TABLE BORDER="0" CELLBORDER="1" CELLSPACING="0">
        <TR>
      <TD BORDER="0">1</TD><TD PORT="p6">122</TD><TD BORDER="0">6</TD>
    </TR>
      </TABLE>>];
    
      N1:p1--N2:p2
      N1:p1--N3:p3
      N2:p2--N4:p4
      N3:p3--N5:p5
      N3:p3--N6:p6
}
```

Giving:
[image]